# How i can do storage event listener?

Tags: javascript, angular

**i want to make event loop for window, when localStorage change - handler start work.**
*I make project on angular 12+*

code below:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener("storage", () => this.updateLocalCart)
    this.updateLocalCart()
}

  updateLocalCart(){
    this.values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    this.items = this.values.map(i => this.appService.getOne(i.id, i.amount))

    let totalpriceArray: number[] = this.values.map(i => i.amount * this.appService.getOne(i.id, i.amount).price)
    this.totalPrice = totalpriceArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    
    if(!this.values || this.values.length <= 0){
      this.voidCart = "You chose nothing"
      this.payButton.nativeElement.style.display = "none"
    }
    else{
      this.voidCart = null
      this.payButton.nativeElement.style.display = "flex"
    }

    this.amountItemsInCart = this.values.length
    if(this.amountItemsInCart == 0 || null)
    {
      this.displayItemCart = "none"
    }
    else{
      this.displayItemCart = "flex"
    }
  }
```

**I tried it make but, its doesnt work :(**

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener("storage", () => this.updateLocalCart)
    this.updateLocalCart()
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need either `window.addEventListener('storage', this.updateLocalCart);` or `window.addEventListener('storage', () => this.updateLocalCart());` Right now you're passing a lambda that returns a method body. Nothing's actually calling the method body.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a function `this.updateLocalCart()` as the second argument to addEventListener() but you're not invoking the updateLocalCart function in your code. Do it the following way:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  window.addEventListener("storage", () => this.updateLocalCart());
  this.updateLocalCart();
}
```

And define the function:

```
updateLocalCart(): void {
  // Add your logic to update the local cart here
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, maybe problem in storage event, because i pass console.log(...) as second argument instead this.updateLocalCart() and console.log(...) not invoking

Comment: Could you please update your question with the code that contains console.log() how you do it? Can you try changing the event listener function to call this.updateLocalCart() instead of console.log(...)?

Comment: I make - window.addEventListener("storage", () => console.log(1)) and eventListener just doesn't see event like "storage".